# google sign_in: How to use redirect_uri in javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-api, firebase-authentication, redirect, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate google sign in my website, and i'm using **firebase** for authentication and later I do authorization the user for access their google drives.

and after getting access of their `Google drives` i want the page to redirect to another page.`(localhost:8080/afterlogin)`, where it will be displayed "**WELCOME**"

however the user doesn't get to the desired page, I've added the exact redierct_uri in the developer console but no help.

here is my code for initializing the auth object.

```
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/afterlogin'

            // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
            //scope: 'additional_scope'
        });
```

i'm using javascript and i read in the docs that javascript api does not use **redirect_uris**.

However in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapi.auth2.ClientConfig)

it is stated that we can add redirect_uris in by using `gapi.auth2.ClientConfig` instead of `gapi.auth2.init`.

but however, using `gapi.auth2.ClientConfig` instead of `gapi.auth2.init` gives me and error. so i added `redirect_uri` in the latter one as seen in the code above. maybe that is why it is not working?

or i'm doing something wrong in using `gapi.auth2.ClientConfig`?

any guesses?

Answer (score 5):

The docs say that you need to override the default **redirect_uri** using **ux_mode='redirect'**. Sometimes Google's documentation is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. I presume you are handling the resulting promises from the code you posted. I would try this:

```
     gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            ux_mode: 'redirect',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/afterlogin'

            // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
            //scope: 'additional_scope'
        });

        auth2.signIn().then(function() {
          var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
          console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        })
```

From the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapi.auth2.ClientConfig)s, under **gapi.auth2.ClientConfig**

[image]

edit - I fixed the issue with the `=` sign

Comment: using Client.Config gives me a type error `Uncaught TypeError: gapi.auth2.ClientConfig is not a function`. Moreover when i do it in `gapi.auth.init` it doesn't give me error, and it is returning a promise like ,
'http://localhost:8080/afterlogin#id_token=the_id_token'.

Comment: moreover is there any reason to make my `gapi` loading script invisible?  like my client_id and other confidential data is being loaded too in the network tab . pardon me to ask this question which might not be related to the present one.

Comment: I've updated my code, it should hopefully get you signed in

Comment: It should be ux_mode:'redirect' and not with '='. I was trying to modify it but I am not able to do it as it changes less than 6 characters.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ux_mode: redirect` not `ux_mode='redirect'`??

Comment: `ux_mode: 'redirect'` if it's a json property (ie. your'e creating the button via javascript.) Or `data-ux_mode = 'redirect'` if you are setting attributes while creating the button in HTML. Not well documented IMBO